# How to bind a controller to dynamically added HTML?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am inject html inputs from the controller and I am trying to bind the scope variables but its not working. 
Here is my code 
**HTML :**

```
    <div ng-controller='addHTML'>
       <div ng-bind-html="trustedHtml"></div>
       <code>{{user}}</code>
    </div>
```

**CSS :**

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
var addHTML = function ($scope,$sce) {
     $scope.user = {};
     $scope.user.someVariable = "";

    //inject some html
    $scope.html = '<input type="text" ng-model="user.someVariable">';
    $scope.trustedHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.html);

};
```

You can find it on the fiddle here : http://jsbin.com/miluguni/1/watch?html,js,output

When typing in the input the scope variables isn't changed.

Comment: You need to run your HTML through the `$compile` service first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ngBindHtml` directive does not $compile templates, it only inserts the template to the DOM.

I copied `ngBindHtml` ( [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.13/src/ng/directive/ngBind.js#L173) ) and added $compile to it

**new Directive:**

```
app.directive('compileHtml',['$sce', '$parse', '$compile', 
  function($sce, $parse, $compile){
  return {
    link: function(scope,element,attr){
      var parsed = $parse(attr.compileHtml);
      function getStringValue() { return (parsed(scope) || '').toString(); }            
      scope.$watch(getStringValue, function (value) {
        var el = $compile($sce.getTrustedHtml(parsed(scope)) || '')(scope);
        element.empty();
        element.append(el);        
      });       
    } 
  };
}]);
```

**Template:**

```
<div compile-html="trustedHtml"></div>
```

#### Here is a demo : http://jsbin.com/miluguni/3/edit